# How to get a local variable from a Runnable Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I have a helper (Not an activity) class that makes a query to an API which has a public function called `run()` and runs on a new thread (As per Android specifications). My `MainActivity` creates a new `MakeQuery` object and runs its `run()` function:

```
MakeQuery q = new MakeQuery();
q.run();
```

However, I need to access a variable from within the thread. Below is a short code sample:

```java
public class MakeQuery implements Runnable {

    private void setNewString(String localThreadString){
       //NewString comes out null...
       NewString  = localThreadString;
    }

    public void run() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

                API Api = new API(keys and tokens);

                //queryAPI() returns string
                setNewString(queryAPI(Api, term1, term2));

                //Don't know how to send intent from here (No context), 
                //I would like:
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.class, AnotherActivity.class)
        }
    }).start();
}
```

ASYNCTASK

```
//This runs in background thread
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    API Api = new API(keys and tokens);

    setNewString(queryAPI(Api, string1, string2));

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("NewString", NewString);
    Log.d(MYTAG, NewString);
}
```

MainActivity

```
public void buttonPressed(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    ...
    MakeQuery task = new MakeQuery(this);
    task.execute();

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have tried to look online for hours. I have tried to do `AsyncTask`, but I am not sure how to implement that with what I have. Furthermore, using `localThread<String>` did not help.

TLDR: I would like to know if it's possible to get NewString so I can pass it through an Intent to another Activity.

**The Solution**
Do not use `Runnable`, create a new `AsyncTask` as shown below. Also, make sure that the `StartActivity` is in the helper class and not in the `MainActivity`. This was because I was not waiting for the task to finish before starting the new activity.

Comment: Why can't you just send the intent from the `Runnable`?

Comment: @Hank I am not really sure how to. I don't know how to create a new Intent from this class, which is not an activity. Does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an implementation using async task:

```
public class MakeQueryTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Context mContext;

    private String newString;

    public MakeQueryTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    //This runs on a background thread
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        API Api = new API(keys and tokens);

        //queryAPI() returns string
        setNewString(queryAPI(Api, term1, term2));

        //You should start your activity on main thread. Do it in onPostExecute() which will be invoked after the background thread is done
        //Intent i = new Intent(mContext, AnotherActivity.class);
        //mContext.startActivity(intent);
        return null;
    }

    private void setNewString(String localThreadString){
        newString  = localThreadString;
    }

    //This will run on UI thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AnotherActivity.class);
       mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And you would execute like this:

```
 MakeQueryTask task = new MakeQueryTask(this); //Here this is an activity (context)
 task.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this will be very helpful, I tried it out, but still got null. I will keep researching! Any other tips?

Comment: newString is null?  Can you log the value of of `newString` in `onPostExecute()`   `Log.d("MYTAG", newString);`

Comment: maybe queryAPI IS returning null. Get it to a local variable and use Debug.Log to print the value, then you can know if the problem is in setNewString or in queryApi.
BTW: This solution is much more clear and according to the Android guidelines than yours.

Comment: I tested queryAPI, which returns a string. Where I am finding trouble is that in the thread I have the correct string, but when I try to access it, it is NULL outside of the thread.

Comment: Can you post your code on how and where you are accessing it

Comment: I have posted the MainActivity, where I have accessed the class.

Comment: ALSO --- within the ASYNCTASK I got the correct string I needed. However, in my Activity2 intent.getExtra, it is returning null. What am I doing wrong? I feel like I am very close!

Comment: That will not work because you are not waiting for the task to finish before starting the new activity. Remove the `startActivity()` from `MainActivity` and put it in `onPostExecute()` of the task, like I have posted on my answer - `onPostExecute` is called after the background thread is done so you will have the variable set at that point.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling this `runnable` from an `activity` or `service`, you could pass in a `context` in the constructor. And just start the activity with the `intent` in the `run()` function.

```
public class MakeQuery implements Runnable {

    private Context context;

    public MakeQuery(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private void setNewString(String localThreadString){
       //NewString comes out null...
       NewString  = localThreadString;
    }

    public void run() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

                API Api = new API(keys and tokens);

                //queryAPI() returns string
                setNewString(queryAPI(Api, term1, term2));

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.class, AnotherActivity.class)
                context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: I tried what you recommended! From my MainActivity I created a new instance of MakeQuery and passed in (this, Activity2Intent). In my constructor I had:
public MakeQuery(Context context, Intent intent){
        this.context = context;
        classIntent = intent;
        string1 = "string1";
        string2 = "string2";
    }

But it did not work. I still got null!

Comment: Where did you get `null`? and what did you want to pass to the other activity?

Comment: I got null from my other Activity (I used intent.getExtra("String")) I checked the output of my API, and it is giving me a correct output. I'll try to be more clear: From my MainActivity I have the helper class MakeQuery (to interface with the API), and run the run() function. I passed in, when making the MakeQuery instance MakeQuery(this, AnotherActivityIntent). AnotherActivityIntent was already created from my MainActivity. In my helper class I tried what you did, creating a new intent -- new Intent(context, AnotherActivity.class) then I used intent.putExtra("String", AnotherActivity)